# The relationship between routes.rb and the "paths" that link to pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, railstutorial.org

This question stems from Hartl's Rails Tutorial (progressed in chapter 9) - sorry if it seems particularly noobish...

Currently, I understand that in the `routes.rb` file, when a page was defined using, for example:

```
match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
```

a link generated in an embedded ruby:

```
<li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
```

would function.  The `help_path`, and specifically the word "path", would correspond to the "#help" defined in routes.

However, the routes file did not define links for items such as `users_path` (used to show all users), or `edit_user_path(current user)` (used to edit settings of the current user) - I was confused as to where they were defined, and how they are able to correctly function and link me the desired places.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're having trouble figuring out what paths you have available to you and you always want to have them in front of you, run `annotate -r` to annotate your `routes.rb` with the information generated from a `rake routes` command ie what paths you have available to you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Paul.  Since my asking the question, I think I've got the hang of routes.rb's basic functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes file does, in fact, get an entry determining the behavior of users ([shown in listing 2.2](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#code%3arails_routes)).  It gets created through the scaffolding described [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec%3ademo_users_resource).

```
resources :users
```

By convention a "resource" entry in your `routes.rb` file  sets up a number of paths that will be associated with users.  Refer to the Rails Guide for a [good overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links!  While I don't entirely understand the concepts now, hopefully going through them will help clear things up.